# TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Se supone que en el siguiente código las letras deberían ir apareciendo una por una automáticamente (imitando el efecto de maquina de escribir) pero en lugar de ello solo aparece la ultima. Itera sobre todos los caracteres. ¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

```
   self.texto = 'Esto es una prueba'
    
    self.explicacion = tk.StringVar()
    self.explicacionLabel = tk.Label(maestro, textvariable= self.explicacion)
    self.explicacionLabel.place(x=250, y=150)
    
    for char in self.texto:
        self.explicacion.set(char)
```

Intente de diferentes formas pero me arrojaba este error:

> TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable

### Actualización

Me di cuenta que nunca tendría el efecto si no daba un tiempo de espera así que agregue un `sleep` de medio segundo pero lo que hace es esperar ese tiempo y después muestra el `label` con el texto ya completo. Agregue un `str` vacío donde ir guardando los caracteres del texto en cada iteración y según yo este fuera apareciendo a medida que se hacia. No ocurre nada de eso.

```
    self.texto = 'Texto de prueba'
    
    self.explicacion = tk.StringVar()
    self.explicacionLabel = tk.Label(maestro)
    self.explicacionLabel.place(x=250, y=150)
    
    listaChar = ''
    for char in self.explicacion:
        self.explicacionLabel.configure(textvariable=self.explicacion)
        sleep(0.5)
        listaChar+= char
        self.explicacion.set(listaChar)
```

Comment: me parece que está bastante incompleto el código o no lo copiaste completo. falta importar el módulo tkinter... ¿estás escribiendolo en el entorno linux o windows?, no entiendo bien lo que quieres que el código haga.

Comment: Me atañí al efecto mínimo verificable. Estoy en windows y ya modifique la pregunta tratando de clarificar lo que buscaba:) Para respuestas así es mejor dejar un comentario y tiene una mejor aceptación por parte de la comunidad. Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el ejemplo a continuación, se prepara una ventana con un botón y una etiqueta. Al presionar el botón, se invoca la función `maquinaEscribir` que va a ir haciendo aparecer el texto letra por letra, con una pequeña espera para lograr el efecto *máquina de escribir* que describes.

Una de las cosas importantes es la llamada al método `update()` de la ventana, sin esta llamada la interfaz de usuario nunca se actualizaría y se vería abruptamente el cambio de ninguna letra a todas solo al final de la ejecución del ciclo.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def maquinaEscribir():
    global texto
    global impreso
    global maquinaLabel
    while len(impreso) < len(texto):
        impreso = texto[0:len(impreso) + 1]
        maquinaLabel['text'] = impreso
        raiz.update()
        time.sleep(0.2)

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.geometry('300x400')
raiz.title("Prueba")
texto = 'Esto es una prueba'
impreso = ''
maquinaLabel = tk.Label(raiz, text="-")
maquinaLabel.place(x=10, y=50)
boton = tk.Button(raiz, text="Empezar efecto máquina", command=maquinaEscribir).place(x=0, y=1)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Como apunte para quien sea que lea esto a futuro. No soy muy de usar variables globales así que opte por pasarlas como argumentos en la función. Funciona exactamente igual.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

class Datos():
    actual = 0

def siguiente():
    if Datos.actual + 1 < len(texto):
        explicacion = texto[Datos.actual + 1]
        explicacionLabel = Label(raiz, text=explicacion).pack()
        Datos.actual += 1

raiz = Tk()
raiz.geometry('300x400')
raiz.title("Prueba")
texto = 'Esto es una prueba'
explicacion = "E"
explicacionLabel = Label(raiz, text=explicacion).pack()
boton = Button(raiz, text="Siguiente", command=siguiente).place(x=0, y=1)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Al pulsar el botón Siguiente, la función `siguiente()` muestra el caracter que hay en la posición guardada en la variable `actual` + 1, e incrementa el valor de actual en una unidad para la siguiente vez que se pulse el botón.

De esta forma, cada vez que se pulsa el botón aparece una letra del texto contenido en la variable `texto`.

Comment: Gracias! La idea es que el texto aparezca automáticamente sin necesidad de estar presionando un botón, como el efecto de maquina de escribir. Creo que tu respuesta me puede orientar a ello:)